# Babel issue from writing to its cache file

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, babeljs

I am attempting to set up a local p5.js project. When I run the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml run --rm app npm run fetch-examples
```

I encounter the following error:

```
Getting p5 user
Babel could not write cache to file: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache/@babel/register/.babel.7.22.5.development.json
due to a permission issue. Cache is disabled.
Deleting old projects...
```

Operating System: Ubuntu

I have deleted all the projects completely and repeated this process more than 4 to 5 times. Additionally, I have cleared all Docker images and thoroughly cleaned everything.

Comment: are you running the command as root?

Comment: No actually i am not running it in root

Comment: Why are you using Docker here?  Can you delete the first 2/3 of the command and `npm run fetch-examples` locally?  Can you [edit] the question to include a more complete setup, in particular including your `docker-compose.yml` file, and your Dockerfile if relevant?

Comment: I am using Docker for installation, and this issue has been resolved for now. Hopefully, everything is working smoothly. However, I am now encountering 'localhost refused to connect'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a permission issue preventing Babel from writing to its cache directory. Try this few steps

**Run as Administrator:**
If you are using a terminal or command prompt, try running it as an administrator or with elevated privileges.

**Check File Permissions:**
Ensure that the user running the command has the necessary permissions to write to the specified directory. You might need to adjust file or folder permissions.

**Clear Cache Manually:**
You can try clearing the Babel cache manually. Delete the contents of the cache directory mentioned in the error message:

```bash
rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache/@babel/register/
```

Then try running your project again.

**Reinstall Node Modules:**
If the issue persists, you might want to try reinstalling your project's node modules:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

If the issue continues, there might be a more specific problem with your project setup that requires further investigation.

Comment: I have tried running it as an administrator, but I am still getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The error has been solved; I just had to add sudo (or run it as a root command).